# systemctl suspend or suspend doesn't stop computer from running

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, systemd, system

When I run systemctl suspend in the terminal or click suspend via the Power off menu, my monitor sleeps but my computer is still running when it should instead have gone to sleep. This happens about 50% of the time. Does anyone know what's happening here and how to fix?

Here's some information about my computer

Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64

Nvidia driver 450

GNOME Shell 3.36.4

Comment: So you are saying Ubuntu will not go into sleep mode?

Comment: @LinuxSurfaceNut yes